# How to count a nested object's element across list of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array of objects in which there are nested array of objects as shown in `Code snippet 1`.
I want to count the number of records within nested array of objects where the `parent_user_id` is equal to the `id`. So according to the result I want, from the `Code snippet 1` the count has to be 4 and the total count has to be after iterating similar outer array of objects.

```
**Code Snippet 1**
[
{
    "name" : "A",
    "description" : null,
    "users" : [
        {
            "id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
            "owner" : "John Doe",
            "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25,
            "status" : "active",
            "parent_user_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
            "recent_items": ["tomato",onion]
        },
        {
            "id" : "63a880a552f40e1d48a3d1dc",
            "owner" : "John Doe 1",
            "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25,
            "parent_user_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
            "recent_items": ["onion"]
        },
        {
            "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48assddd"
            "owner" : "John Doe 2",
            "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25,
            "parent_user_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
        },
        {
            "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48a3d207"
            "owner" : "John Doe 11",
            "dt" : "2022-12-25,
            "status" : "inactive",
            "parent_user_id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48a3d207",
        },
        {
            "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agfmmb"
            "owner" : "John Doe 112",
            "dt" : "2022-12-25,
            "status" : "active",
            "parent_user_id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agfmmb",
            "recent_items": ["tomato"]
        }
        {
            "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agggg"
            "owner" : "John SS",
            "dt" : "2022-12-25,
            "status" : "inactive",
            "parent_user_id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agggg",
        }
        {
            "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d487777"
            "owner" : "John SS",
            "dt" : "2022-12-25,
            "parent_user_id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agggg",
        }
    ]
}
]
```

The solutions I tried involved for loops and lot of iteration, is there any simple way to achieve this in Javascript or typescript?

Comment: You can `.filter()` the array with a predicate function that performs the test on `id` and `parent_user_id` and then check the `.length` of the result.

Comment: @Pointy can you please help me out using a pseudo code?

Comment: `your_array.reduce((prev, cur) => cur.users.filter(u => u.id === u.parent_user_id).length + prev, 0);`

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "name" : "A",
        "description" : null,
        "users" : [
            {
                "id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
                "owner" : "John Doe",
                "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25",
                "status" : "active",
                "parent_user_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
                "recent_items": ["tomato","onion"]
            },
            {
                "id" : "63a880a552f40e1d48a3d1dc",
                "owner" : "John Doe 1",
                "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25",
                "parent_user_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
                "recent_items": ["onion"]
            },
            {
                "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48assddd",
                "owner" : "John Doe 2",
                "purchase_date" : "2022-12-25",
                "parent_user_id" : "63a8808c52f40e1d48a3d1da",
            },
            {
                "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48a3d207",
                "owner" : "John Doe 11",
                "dt" : "2022-12-25",
                "status" : "inactive",
                "parent_user_id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48a3d207",
            },
            {
                "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agfmmb",
                "owner" : "John Doe 112",
                "dt" : "2022-12-25",
                "status" : "active",
                "parent_user_id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agfmmb",
                "recent_items": ["tomato"]
            },
            {
                "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agggg",
                "owner" : "John SS",
                "dt" : "2022-12-25",
                "status" : "inactive",
                "parent_user_id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agggg",
            },
            {
                "id" : "63a880f752f40e1d487777",
                "owner" : "John SS",
                "dt" : "2022-12-25",
                "parent_user_id" : "63a880f752f40e1d48agggg",
            }
        ]
    }
    ]

const returnedArr = arr[0].users.filter((item, index) => item.id === item.parent_user_id)
console.log(returnedArr.length);
```